# samba server using active directory logons

Tags: networking, server, permissions, samba, file-sharing

there is plenty of information on samba, and accessing the server just by the user name and smbpasswd you created on samba.

However, lets say I have a samba server and I joined it to the windows domain "AD"
i have 100 users on windows AD.

how would set credentials and permissions for all 100 users on my AD windows server instead of creating a user one by one on linux samba server so they can see my files without me having to create a user on ubuntu server samba?

Answer (score 0):

For an existing Samba server using NT4-style authentication, there is an [excellent manual](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba_Classic_Upgrade_%28NT4-style_domain_to_AD%29) over at the samba.org domain.

Basically what it drills down to is:

- Find out which AD servers run what (including `ldap`, AD, ...)
- Prevent duplicate SIDs
- Correct duplicate user/group names (which AD doesn't like and is standard behaviour in Linux)
- Start [the actual upgrade process](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba_Classic_Upgrade_%28NT4-style_domain_to_AD%29#The_classicupgrade_process)